# What is the best way to store distances with H2O?

Tags: r, optimization, parallel-processing, h2o

Supose I have 2 data.frames and I want to calculate the euclidean distance between all of the rows of them. My code is:

```
set.seed(121)
# Load library
library(h2o)
system.time({
  h2o.init()
  # Create the df and convert to h2o frame format
  df1 <- as.h2o(matrix(rnorm(7500 * 40), ncol = 40))
  df2 <- as.h2o(matrix(rnorm(1250 * 40), ncol = 40))
  # Create a matrix in which I will record the distances
  matrix1 <- as.h2o(matrix(0, nrow = 7500, ncol = 40))
  # Loop to calculate all the distances
  for (i in 1:nrow(df2)){
    matrix1[, i] <- h2o.sqrt(h2o.distance(df1, df2[, i]))
  }
})
```

I´m sure there is more efficient way to store it into a matrix.

Comment: I can't tell, it doesn't work on my computer.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to calculate the distance inside a loop, H2O's distance function can efficiently calculate distances for all the rows. For two data frames with `n x k` and `m x k` dimensions, you can find the `n x m` distance matrix in a following way:

```
distance_matrix <- h2o.distance(df1, df2, 'l2')
```

There is no need to take the square root, since [`h2o.distance()` function](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/h2o/versions/3.10.5.3/topics/h2o.distance) allows you to specify what distance measure to use: `"l1"` - Absolute distance (L1 norm), `"l2"` - Euclidean distance (L2 norm), `"cosine"` - Cosine similarity and `"cosine_sq"` - Squared Cosine similarity.

Following your example, the code to calculate the Euclidean distance matrix will be:

```
library(h2o)
h2o.init()
df1 <- as.h2o(matrix(rnorm(7500 * 40), ncol = 40))
df2 <- as.h2o(matrix(rnorm(1250 * 40), ncol = 40))
distance_matrix <- h2o.distance(df1, df2, 'l2')
```

resulting in a matrix with dimensions `7500 rows x 1250 columns`.